# Data structure handle as array

Tags: arrays, json, vb.net, data-structures

i'm use data structure to store JSON data

```
 Class node
        Friend ReadOnly position As Integer
        Friend ReadOnly position_Array As Integer

        Public index As Integer = 0

        Friend head As String
        Friend parent As node
        Friend is_array_item As Boolean = False
        '  Friend attrib As node_val
        Friend child_list As New List(Of node_val)
        Friend tail As String
        Sub New(ByRef a As node, ByRef pos As Integer) ', b As node_val)
            parent = a
            '  attrib = b
            position = pos ' a.child_list.Count - 1
        End Sub

    End Class
```

dim n as new node
n.child_list(8).val

```
dim n as new node
n.child_list(8).val
```

i want to this class's object handle as array

```
n(8).val
```

how i do this

Comment: It's not clear if you are trying to access the `node` object's `child_list` or trying to create an array of `node` objects. If you want to access `child_list` by default, you can declare a [Default Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/how-to-declare-and-call-a-default-property) on the `node` class. If you want to make an array of `node` objects, you can use a [List(Of node)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-6.0): `Dim nodes As New List(Of node)`

Comment: i want to use  n(8).val instead n.child_list(8).val

Comment: for example look string data structure dim s as string    s(8) can get 8 member of character list on string structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a [Default Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/how-to-declare-and-call-a-default-property) to your `node` class that will return an item from your `child_list`:

```
Class node

    Friend ReadOnly position As Integer
    Friend ReadOnly position_Array As Integer
    Public index As Integer = 0
    Friend head As String
    Friend parent As node
    Friend is_array_item As Boolean = False
    Friend child_list As New List(Of node)
    Friend tail As String

    Sub New(ByRef a As node, ByRef pos As Integer)
        parent = a
        position = pos
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Gets or sets child node.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="index"></param>
    Default Property Child(ByVal index As Integer) As node
        Get
            If index >= 0 And index < child_list.Count Then
                Return child_list.Item(index)
            Else
                ' index is out of bounds
                Return Nothing
            End If
        End Get
        Set(value As node)
            If index < 0 Then Return
            If index < child_list.Count Then
                child_list.Item(index) = value
            Else
                ' Add node at end of list
                child_list.Add(value)
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

Please be careful with the setter on the `Child` property. Items in a list should be inserted sequentially.